# How to clear DNN cache after a setting has been changed in a custom module

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke

How can I programmatically clear the DNN cache when I have updated a setting in one of my DNN modules?

I have the following code which checks if something is cached in DNN.

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads the Web Home Page Categories set up in ERP
/// </summary>
/// <param name="requestData"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <remarks>RB 2017-08-17
/// RB 2017-09-18: Added Caching so that the result is loaded from cache instead of calling the server again</remarks>
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public string GetWebHomePagePublishingCategories([FromBody] ParrotRequestBase requestData)
{
    GlobalSettings GV = GetGlobalSettingsForCurrentUser(requestData.UserID, requestData.CompanyID);

    string cacheKey = Constants.conWebHomePagesCacheKey; //"WebHomePagesCacheKey";

    var cache = DataCache.GetCache(cacheKey);

    if (cache == null)
    {
        var timeOut = 20 * Convert.ToInt32(Host.PerformanceSetting);

        cache = m_PubCtrl.WebHomePageCategories(GV.Globalvars, requestData);
        if (timeOut > 0 & cache != null)
        {
            DataCache.SetCache(cacheKey, cache, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeOut));
        }
    }

    return cache.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataCache` class in `DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities`

```
DataCache.ClearCache();
//or
DataCache.ClearModuleCache(TabId);
```

There are a lot more "Clear..." methods, so check them out if one of them suits your needs.